# Firebase query undefined when using react-firebase-hooks

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was following [Fireship's building chat app video](https://youtu.be/zQyrwxMPm88?list=PLEKwZvzYD7eXDkrFk6H9zUPeFTVh6AMu9&t=213) (this part is around 3:30-4 minutes) but I am trying do something different, just using it for oauth and database setup help. I made a simple database on it, then tried to follow the query format where the collection grab and query seem to work fine since I can console.log them. But when I try to use the collection data, it is undefined. I also found another post on here similar that queried it differently and tried to use an grab a specific variable, but doing that just left me with an error saying "query2 is not a function". So below I added 2 versions of what I tested. ListItem is the collection name, and checked is one of my variables in the document.

```
function GrabData(){
const dataRef = firestore.collection('ListItem')
console.log(dataRef)
const query = dataRef.orderBy('createdAt')
console.log(query)
const [items1] = useCollectionData(firestore.collection("ListItem"))
console.log(items1)
const [items2] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'checked'})
console.log("items = " + items2)
```

[image: console log of collection and query]

UPADTE: From the error message it seems I needed to add permissions. However, instead of undefined it simply returns empty arrays. And I querying it incorrectly or missing something?

```
function GrabData(){
const dataRef = firestore.collection('ListItem')
console.log(dataRef)
const query = dataRef.orderBy('createdAt')
console.log(query)
const [items] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'checked'})
console.log(items)
const [values, loading, error, snapshot] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'checked'});
console.log(values)
console.log(snapshot)
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 2: I changed the if false to if true in the firebase edit rules tab

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {

      allow read, write: if true;

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Try to add the other 3 returns from the [documentation](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#usecollectiondata:~:text=of%20the%20data-,useCollectionData,-const%20%5Bvalues). Try this instead: `const [items2, loading, error, snapshot] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'checked'})`.

Comment: The error helped me figure out that I needed to give permission for the query to go through. However now it just returns an empty array. I updated my original post to show my database. I am unsure if I am querying this incorrectly or if I'm missing something. Please let me know and thank you for the help so far

Comment: That means that you have a permission issue on your Firestore Security Rules. Have you tried to modify your Firestore Security Rules? Have you authenticated before querying? Include your Firestore Security Rules on your question to check why you have a permission issue.

Comment: By default, your rules should be like this: `match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }`. If this is the case, you should be authenticating before sending a query to Firestore to proceed. For testing, try changing it to: `match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }`. It should allow you to read and write unauthenticated.

Comment: I just updated my post. I changed it to if true when it had been if false and that made it so there is no more error and that it is no longer "undefined" however I now get it as "[]". So I am unsure if I am just querying incorrectly at this point

Comment: I'm not sure what data you want to query but I created a simple query based on your Firestore DB. Try this: `const [items2, loading, error] = 
useCollectionData(query(
        collection(firestore, "ListItem"),
        where("checked", "==", true)
    ));`

Comment: I think the problem was that I was defining query higher up, because the error I kept getting was query2 is not a function. When I commented out that query variable it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem I had, edit the firestore permissions from "allow read, write: if false;" change the false to true. Also, make sure that you don't define a variable with the name query since you need to import the query function from firebase/firestore. Otherwise it will be overwritten and throw an error